# How can I make a basic authorization with angular HttpClient and connect with an API Request?

Tags: http-headers, httprequest, angular5, angular-httpclient

I tried to connect an API with basic authorization but the server doesn't give me access it return a 401 (unauthorised). My code is:

```
getApi() {
        console.log('here i am in the method for get extensions');
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ***********************'
        });
        const options = {
            headers,
            withCredentials: true
        };
        // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
        return this.http.post('https://10.100.43.241/json', this.jsonBody, options).map((response: Response) => {
            const resToJSON = JSON.stringify(response);
            console.log('i am going to return jsonfrom method');
            return resToJSON;
        });
    }
```

I tried also with postman an it is working as well:

[image: postman an it is working as well].

I really need to know how can I solve this problem of connection or authorization.

note: I am not the administrator of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this architecture.

Component:

```
this._appApiService.getApi(this.jsonBody).subscribe(result => {
   this.resToJSON = result; 
});
```

Service:

```
getApi(jsonBody: any) {
    // add authorization header with jwt token
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token });
    let options = { headers: headers };

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'https://10.100.43.241/json', this.jsonBody , options);
  }
```